# Why is While Loop and For Loop giving different results when there is a function call inside the loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So I have a block of code like this:

```
var hello3 = [];

  function testfunc3() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
      hello3[i] = {
        another3: function() {
          return i;
        }
      };
      i++;
    }
  }

  function alertnow3() {
    alert(hello3[6].another3());
  }
```

When I call testfunc3 first, and then call alertnow3, the alert I am getting is "10"

Then I changed the code block to this:

```
var hello1 = [];

  function testfunc1() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      hello1[i] = {
        another1: function() {
          return i;
        }
      };
    }
  }

  function alertnow1() {
    alert(hello1[6].another1());
  }
```

Now when I call testfunc1 first, and then call alertnow1, the alert I am getting is "6"

Then I changed the code to this:

```
var hello2 = [];

  function testfunc2() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ) {
      hello2[i] = {
        another2: function() {
          return i;
        }
      };
      i++;
    }
  }

  function alertnow2() {
    alert(hello2[6].another2());
  }
```

Now when I call testfunc2 first, and then call alertnow2, the alert I am getting is "7"

Why are the responses different for the 3 blocks of code? I was expecting all responses to be 6.

Here is a codesandbox link for you guys to check (All 3 cases given above is demonstrated in the code. Click on "Click Here" first and then "Alert Now": https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-microservice-mtl1t?file=/src/App.js:329-577

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486)

Comment: I am aware of closures, so I used let instead of var for all initializations. Are you sure this is the reason in my case?